# Find minimum length interval that has K as its factor

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer K and a list of N integers. We need to find all possible shortest intervals in the list, such that the product of the integers in each interval, is a multiple of K.

Example : Let N=6, K=5 and array be [2,9,4,3,16] then here minimum length of interval is 2 whose product are multiple of K.

Intervals: [1, 2] , [2, 3] , [3, 4] , [4, 5].

Now I need to find both minimum length and all intervals start and end.

But the problem is constraints are large, 1≤N≤2×10^5 , 1≤K≤10^17 and array elements are upto 10^15.

Comment: You are obviously missing some info/constraints. Suppose k=8 and all numbers in array are 2. Then any 3 combinations(2*2*2) will work and it will require at least O(n^3) time to print them which will timeout. Maybe the integers are unique?

Comment: None of the integers in your list is a multiple of K = 5 -- so how can you get subintervals of that list whose product is a multiple of 5?

Comment: I think that' just a bad example. If K is prime it must occur in the list and the minimal length intervals will be of length 1. If K was 9, then two consecutive 3's will get you an interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a segment tree to be able to compute `product(a[i...j])%K` in `O(log N)`.

From the principle that if `product(a[i...j])%K==0`, then `product(a[i...j+k])%K==0`, you can, for each `i`, perform a binary search to find the first `j` where `product(a[i..j])%K==0`.

In the first pass, find what's the minimum length. Then do another pass finding and printing which `i`'s have that length.

That's `O(n log^2 n)`. For 2*10^5 that should be enough. Specially given the answer can have `O(n^2)` items (e.g. n/2 subarrays with n/2 items each).